# What is the best approach to create a Visual Studio-like Start Window using ReactiveUI?

Tags: c#, mvvm, reactiveui

I want to make a Start / Welcome / Solution selection window which has similar functionalities to the one used in VS19 / VS22, but I'm not sure how to do it exactly.

For more context, my current StartWindowView has a "Create New Project..." button, which should replace the entire window content with a 2-page project creation wizard.

Page 1 should be "Basic Options" where on the bottom there are "Cancel" and "Next" buttons ("Cancel" goes back to the original StartView and "Next" goes to Page2View).

Page 2 should be "Extra Options" where on the bottom there are "Back" and "Finish" buttons ("Back" goes back to Page1View and "Finish" goes back to the StartView, returning a ProjectModel)

From my understanding, these are the ViewModels I'd have to deal with:

```
StartWindowViewModel // Main window host (possible router)
    StartViewModel // Main project selection view
    ProjectCreationViewModel // Possible router for Page1 & Page2
        ProjectCreationPage1ViewModel // Basic options
        ProjectCreationPage2ViewModel // Extra options
```

My idea was to use Routing, but I don't know if that's the right approach, since I'm not sure if the data between Page1 and Page2 will be preserved when going back and forth.
Also, the routing examples I saw for ReactiveUI have fixed "Back" and "Next" buttons on the bottom, therefore it makes me think that this might not be the solution for my problem, since pressing the "Create New Project..." button replaces the StartViewModel with the ProjectCreationViewModel, making manual navigation impossible.

I might be completely wrong though. I'm really unsure on how to approach this problem.

EDIT: This is how the VS22 start window looks like:
[image]
and this is what happens when you press the button marked in red:
[image]
As you can see, the entire window changes the current View.

Comment: I've updated the post with screenshots of the VS22 Start Window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not terribly difficult, just keep an observable collection of your view model stack, and always display the last one (or the first one, it's easier with WPF bindings). Note that I'll be referring to this as a stack, but there is no `ObservableStack<>` already built for you. Either use an `ObservableCollection<>` or build your own observable stack.

Then as you need to navigate "into" your wizard (new project, clone a repository, etc), you simply push the new child view model onto the stack. When you need to navigate "out of" your wizard (ie, on Cancel), pop the last view model from the stack.

The last step is to associate your views to view models (using `DataTemplate` in a high-level resource block, either a global one or a local one in your start page) and then bind your view model stack's top to your main window (the shell that has a `ContentControl` bound to the top of your stack).

Comment: The Stack idea sounds very reasonable and seems like the same approach VS is using, now that I look at it.
I still don't know where I should put the Stack though and how I should handle it?
Let's say, the Top item in the stack is the Page2ViewModel, and when I press "Back", how is the stack supposed to know that it should Pop that page? Should I use some kind of Message Bus?

Comment: The child VM would get a handle to the main window VM in the constructor, and through it it can call a command to pop itself off the stack when needed. That's what you bind to your "Back" button.